# Unkey a datatable in R

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a data table of the foll structure. ( A simplistic scenario)

```
dtf <- data.table (CUSTKEY=c("a","b","c","d"),num =     rep(c(2,3)),Revenue=c(500,60,56,450))
dtf
    CUSTKEY num Revenue
1:       a   2     500
2:       b   3      60
3:       c   2      56
4:       d   3     450
```

At some point  "revenue" column became a key.
 Naturally, this reorders the table.

```
 setkey(dtf,Revenue)
 dtf
      CUSTKEY num Revenue
  1:       c   2      56
  2:       b   3      60
  3:       d   3     450
  4:       a   2     500
```

**How do I completely randomize the datatable again wrt the revenue column?**

(My use case is that I need to run kmeans on this column for clustering. The unordered revenue column is preferred for that process. However this might be a  need for other purposes too)

Comment: If you also want to remove the key you'll need `setkey(dtf, NULL)`

Comment: and most operations on a `data.table` that used to require a key can now be done on-the-fly, so may be worth seeing if the line of code that sets the key in the first place is even necessary.

Comment: It's neat to know the NULL way to remove a key @SymbolixAU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
> scramble <- dtf[ dtf[ , sample(.N, .N)] ]
> scramble
   CUSTKEY num Revenue
1:       c   2      56
2:       b   3      60
3:       a   2     500
4:       d   3     450
```

It didn't really "take" or durably succeed until I saved it to a second item (or perhaps itself).

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the following code to remove the keys.

```
setkey(dtf,NULL)
```

After doing that, if you want to randomize the order of rows in your table, you can use the 'sample' function.

```
dtf <- dtf[sample(1:nrow(dtf)), ]
```

Comment: In data.table, .N is a synonym for nrow(dtf) inside braces (see `help('special-symbols')`), so you can achieve the same results with:
`dtf <- dtf[sample.int(.N) ]`